# Excel Desktop - Office.context.document.settings.get() didn't working

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-2016, excel-addins

When the excel file is reopened then it did not persist the saved settings.
I am able to do Office.context.document.settings.set('key', value). But when I try to get settings using Office.context.document.settings.get() it didn't working.

I want the state should be saved and the next time when we open the document we should retrieve the saved values

I am using Excel 2016 standard version
Build Version - (16.0.4266.1001) 64 bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the [saveAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.settings?view=common-js-preview#office-office-settings-saveasync-member(1)) method of the `Office.Settings` interface to persist the in-memory copy of the settings property bag in the document.

Any settings previously saved by an add-in are loaded when it is initialized, so during the lifetime of the session you can just use the `set` and `get` methods to work with the in-memory copy of the settings property bag. When you want to persist the settings so that they are available the next time the add-in is used, use the `saveAsync` method.